# Sort an array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

Given the following Datatype

```
public class FileDefinition
{
    public String headercode;
    public String text;
    public String fileext;
    public int readNumBytes;

    public FileDefinition(String headercode, String fileext, String text, int readNumBytes)
    {
        this.headercode = headercode;
        this.fileext = fileext;
        this.text = text;
        this.readNumBytes = readNumBytes;
    }
}
```

I have something like this:

```
    knownfiles[90] = new FileDefinition(
        "^2E524543",
        "ivr",
        "RealPlayer video file (V11 and later)",
        DEFAULT_READ_BYTES
    );

        knownfiles[89] = new FileDefinition(
            "^.{2,4}2D6C68",
            "lha",
            "Compressed archive file",
            DEFAULT_READ_BYTES
        );

        knownfiles[88] = new FileDefinition(
            "^2A2A2A2020496E7374616C6C6174696F6E205374617274656420",
            "log",
            "Symantec Wise Installer log file",
            DEFAULT_READ_BYTES
        );
```

Question:
How do i sort by the "headercode" field?

```
FileDefinition[] filedefs = clsFiledefs.getFileDefinitions();
FileDefinition[] filedefs2 = SOMEMAGIC(filedefs);
```

I need it to get my array ordered by the longest field to the shortest.

I have tried to `Array.Sort(X,y)`, but that did not work.
Thanks in advance for all answers.

Comment: The title said "multidimensional" but the arrays are just one-dimensional. I changed that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following:

```
Array.Sort( filedefs, ( a, b ) => a.headercode.Length.CompareTo( b.headercode.Length ) );
```

if you don't want to alter the original array then

```
FileDefinition[] filedefs2 = (FileDefinition[])filedefs.Clone();
Array.Sort( filedefs2, ( a, b ) => a.headercode.Length.CompareTo( b.headercode.Length ) );
```

Comment: Nice, but now i have the shortest first. How can i order it DESC, so the longest length is first?

Comment: Array copying is not good. In second solution it's better to use LINQ's OrderBy.

Comment: What do you mean is not good? It's much faster than the LINQ's OrderBy + ToArray

Answer (score 2):

You can do this

```
var sorted = filedefs.OrderBy(x=> x.headercode, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase).ToArray();
var sorted = filedefs.OrderByDescending(x=> x.headercode, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase).ToArray();
```

if you want to order by their length

```
var sorted = filedefs.OrderBy(x=> x.headercode.Length).ToArray();
var sorted = filedefs.OrderByDescending(x=> x.headercode.Length).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a [`List<FileDefinition>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/vstudio/6sh2ey19.aspx) (Because it's a lot easier to add items into a List as into an array) and than just use the [`Linq`](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b) expression [`OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderby.aspx) to order your list.

`knownfiles.OrderBy(s => s.readNumBytes);`

Comment: It should work with Array.Sort as well. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5430016/better-way-to-sort-array-in-descending-order