# C# array.sort() for multiple arrays in Descending order

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

I Have two arrays named weights and values. I wanted to sort Values based on the sorting of Weights. That works perfectly fine by doing

```
Array.Sort(Weights,Values);
```

This gives me arrays sorted in ascending order. I wanted to do the same sorting in Descending order. Is there a better way to do without using
 `Array.Reverse(Weights) and Array.Reverse(Values)`

Comment: How long are `Weights` and `Values`?

Comment: Write a custom comparator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to use [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8kwfbye(v=vs.110).aspx) and provide a custom `IComparer<T>`. The relatively new [`Comparer<T>.Create`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh737198(v=vs.110).aspx) method makes this a lot easier because you can simply turn a delegate or lambda expression into an `IComparer<T>` without having to code a full implementation yourself. It's not clear from the question what the datatype of `Weights` and `Values` are, but here's an example using `double[]` and `int[]` respectively:

```
var Weights = new [] { 1.7, 2.4, 9.1, 2.1, };
var Values = new [] { 7, 9, 5, 3, };

Array.Sort(Weights, Values, Comparer<double>.Create((x, y) => y.CompareTo(x)));
```

And just for fun, here's a solution using LINQ:

```
var pairs = Weights.Zip(Values, Tuple.Create);
var orderedPairs = pairs.OrderByDescending(x => x.Item1);
```

I'd also recommend that you consider using a class to store weights and values together rather than as two separate arrays.

Comment: Than you for the answer. Weights is a int array and values is double array. How can i handle that scenario using the code above ? Can you provide an example ?

Comment: @Srini All you'd have to do is change `Comparer<double>` to `Comparer<int>`.

Answer (score 2):

First, create a structure that holds the corresponding items.

```
var items =
    Weights
        .Select((weight, index) =>
            new
            {
                Weight = weight,
                Value = Values[index]
            }
        )
        .OrderByDescending(item => item.Weight)
        .ToArray();
```

Then you can get the sorted array back:

```
Weights = items.Select(item => item.Weight).ToArray();
Values = items.Select(item => item.Value).ToArray();
```

But you may also try one of the answers here:
[Better way to sort array in descending order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5430016/better-way-to-sort-array-in-descending-order)