# C# Sort vs JavaScript Sort

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net, sorting

I am having following array as input to sort values in descending order:

```
var cars = ["8587009748118224023Po","8587009748118224023PP","8587009748118224023P,","8587009748118224023P$","8587009748118224023P<","8587009748118224023P?"]
```

In C#, I am using **OrderByDescending** and getting following output

**C# code**:

```
var rslt= cars.OrderByDescending(a => a);
```

**Result** (commas added after each value):

```
8587009748118224023PP,
8587009748118224023Po,
8587009748118224023P<,
8587009748118224023P?,
8587009748118224023P,
,
8587009748118224023P$,
```

In Javascript, I am using **sort** and **reverse** and getting following different result

**javascript code**:

```
cars.sort();
cars.reverse();
```

**Result**:

```
8587009748118224023Po,
8587009748118224023PP,
8587009748118224023P?,
8587009748118224023P<,
8587009748118224023P,
,
8587009748118224023P$
```

Can anyone help me how to sort values in C# as like JavaScript?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5430016/better-way-to-sort-array-in-descending-order

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try changing the StringComparer:

```
Array.Sort(cars, StringComparer.Ordinal);
Array.Reverse(cars);
```

Comment: You are right, the following code gives the correct result in my case in C#.       var rslt = cars.OrderByDescending(a => a, StringComparer.Ordinal);

Comment: And though @Rajesh [deleted his answer explaining this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45627427/1028230), this gives you a hint of how to accomplish the flip side of this too -- if you want JavaScript to sort like C# does by default, you use a sorting algorithm that employs [`localCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare).

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the Javascript is doing a case insensitive sort.  For C# you need to explicitly tell it to do this.  So this should work;

```
var rslt = cars.OrderByDescending(a => a, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

**Edit:**

After update from OP then he discovered that the ignore case was not required.  So the following worked;

```
var rslt = cars.OrderByDescending(a => a, StringComparer.Ordinal);
```

Comment: It gives following different result (not like javascript) 8587009748118224023PP,8587009748118224023Po,8587009748118224023P?,8587009748118224023P<,8587009748118224023P,,8587009748118224023P$

Comment: [`If compareFunction is not supplied, elements are sorted by converting them to strings and comparing strings in Unicode code point order`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Description)

Comment: @jason.kaisersmith, your answer gave me the clue and following line gives the exact result in C# as like javascript.   var rslt = cars.OrderByDescending(a => a, StringComparer.Ordinal);