# Order By vs Sort for creating ordered collection

Tags: c#, sorting, collections

I have been through this article 
[C# Sort and OrderBy comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832684/c-sharp-sort-and-orderby-comparison)

But the answer accepted in this question is obscure to me.

**I can't decide when I should use Sort or when I should use OrderBy.**

Is there anyway to recommend sort or order by over each other.

So, please give me a succinct answer without any complication.

Comment: The answer on the linked question is quite clear: It doesn't matter for speed. Use whatever is most convenient.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

- You use `Sort` when you want to sort the original list. It performs an in-place sort.
- You use `OrderBy` when you don't want to change the original list as it returns an `IOrderedEnumerable<T>` that leaves the original list untouched. Or when you don't have a list but some other enumerable.

Comment: I'd add "Use `OrderBy` when you need a [Stable Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_sort#Stability)

Comment: Also, OrderBy returns a IOrderedEnumerable<T>, and you can chain other LINQ functions after it (for example, .Select(p => ....))

Comment: @MatthewWatson: Good point. I wasn't aware of that difference but the MSDN confirms it. `Sort` performs an unstable sort, `OrderBy` performs a stable sort.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth, I have a custom collection class which inherits from       
ICollection.Right before i sort the collection i need to check for invalid entities in the collection, therefore i use where clause and then i use sort since where clause gives new collection rather so sorting is performed on different collection rather than on main collection object,
Code tends to be like

m_objUndoRedoObservableCollection.Where(obj=>obj.isValid).sort(custom comparer i pass) 
 so is there any way to do sort on the main collecton with the help of where and sort

Comment: @YogeshJoshi: The code you showed in your comment won't compile. There is no `sort` or `Sort` defined for `IEnumerable<T>`. To answer the question: You can simply do this: `m_objUndoRedoObservableCollection = new ObservableCollection<YourType>(m_objUndoRedoObservableCollection.Where(obj=>obj.isValid).OrderBy(...));`

Comment: @DanielHilgarth MyMistake( yes that is right we have to use ToList() before calling sort())

Comment: @DanielHilgarth i want in-place sorting therefore i can't use order by. i want to use sort with where is that possible anyhow.

Comment: @YogeshJoshi: In that case the code could look like this: `m_objUndoRedoObservableCollection = new ObservableCollection<YourType>(m_objUndoRedoObservableCollection.Where(obj=>obj.‌​isValid).ToList().Sort(<custom comparer>));`. However, in this scenario it is better to use `OrderBy` because when using `Sort` - which requires `ToList` - you copy the objects twice. Once into the temporary list you sort on and once into the new observable collection.

Comment: @YogeshJoshi: You can't perform an in-place sort, because you want to also perform a filtering.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30043/discussion-between-yogesh-joshi-and-daniel-hilgarth)

Comment: @YogeshJoshi: I am not available for chat. If you have further questions, post them as such. This is already getting way out of hand here in the comments.