# avoid List.Sort resort if sort indicator remains the same

Tags: c#, sorting, compact-framework

I have a `List<Foo> fooList;` where Foo is defined as

```
class Foo
{
    public int Importance { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now i add three objects to `fooList`

```
fooList.Add(new Foo { Name = "Foo1", Importance = 1 });
fooList.Add(new Foo { Name = "Foo2", Importance = 1 });
fooList.Add(new Foo { Name = "Foo3", Importance = 1 });
```

Now i sort by importance

```
fooList.Sort((a, b) => a.Importance.CompareTo(b.Importance));
```

and dump the list, i get

```
Foo3, Foo2, Foo1
```

doing a sort again gives me

```
Foo1, Foo2, Foo3
```

Both results are correct, but they are confusing to my users.
Is there a way to avaoid resorting?

Comment: Have something like created time. If `Importance` is equal sort with `createdtime`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the comparison of the field that you want to sort on falls out as equal, then compare on something else, for example the objects themselves:

```
fooList.Sort((a, b) => {
  int result = a.Importance.CompareTo(b.Importance);
  if (result == 0) {
    result = a.CompareTo(b);
  }
  return result;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe using [`OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx) and [`ThenBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534743.aspx)

```
fooList = fooList.OrderBy(x=>x.Importance).ThenBy(x=>x.Name).ToList();
```

It will sort first after Importance then after Name so results will be the same. See demo below:

http://ideone.com/jf6Am9

EDIT:

here you can find comparision between `OrderBy` and `Sort` so you can consider chaning to `OrderBy` [C# Sort and OrderBy comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832684/c-sharp-sort-and-orderby-comparison). In short: `OrderBy` is comparably fast and this solution looks cleaner :)

Comment: The code in the answer (or the demo) doesn't change the list. You have to use something like `.ToList()` to realise the result so that the code does anything at all, and assign the result back to the variable (or a new variable).

Comment: +1 for the LINQ suggestion, but the comment that `OrderBy` is faster is highly dependent on the situation. On my machine (i7 3rd gen Release build on 64bit .NET 4.5), `Sort` outperforms `OrderBy` around in all cases mentioned in that Darin's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1832713/69809) by up to three times. Since `OrderBy` creates three additional arrays of length of the `IEnumerable` and then runs Quicksort (check the source for `OrderedEnumerable`), I don't see how it could possibly be faster. LINQ *is* a much cleaner solution, however, and one that should be preferred in most cases.

Comment: @Groo really? I thought it's faster, but thanks for clarification. I'll change my answer and suggest that it's cleaner and comparably fast ;) I'll keep your suggestions in mind :)