# Order list elements by properties sub properties

Tags: c#, linq, list

A list should be ordered by a property which is sub property of a object in a list.

```
pList = pList
        .OrderBy(x => x.GetType()
            .GetProperty(sortBasedValue)
            .GetValue(x, null))
        .ToList();
```

Will sort all Elements in the list, but some subelements have multiple properties.
Already tried `subitem.value` as `sortBasedValue` but will not work.

Comment: So `sortBasedValue` is a string like `"Name"` and you want to pass it a chid property like `"Address.City"`?

Comment: @DStanley Most likely it is, as GetProperty only takes that as first parameter.

Comment: @Xiaoy312 I know how `GetProerty` works; I was more interested in how the OP wants to pass in the sub-property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GetProperty takes the name of the property as parameter, but you can't use it to fletch its property's property directly. You would need to chain it.

```
Enumerable.Empty<object>()
    // looks from the naming its a private variable, 
    //so you might want to call it via , GetProperty("subitem", BindingFlags.NonPublic) 
    .OrderBy(x => 
    {
        var subitem = x.GetType().GetProperty("subitem").GetValue(x);
        return subitem.GetType().GetProperty("value").GetValue(subitem);
    })
    .ToList();
```

If you have the type of the `pList`, I would suggest you to use a property selector aka `Func<TObject, TPropertyToOrderBy>` and give it to the `OrderBy`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a custom IComparer and use the sort method.

The solution is here [C# Sort and OrderBy comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832684/c-sharp-sort-and-orderby-comparison)