# Speed of Linq OrderBy() vs List.Sort()

Tags: c#, performance, linq, sorting, ienumerable

Here's an enumeration of random integers:

```
var r = new Random();
var e = Enumerable.Repeat(1, 10_000_000).Select( _ => r.Next());
```

Which version do you think is faster:

```
var result = e.OrderBy(x => x).Last(); //materialize the IEnumerable
```

or

```
var l = e.ToList();
l.Sort();
var result = l.Last();
```

I was hoping that `.OrderBy(x => x).Last()` in the first example would be 
optimized to only sort a small subset of the list or to just do an O(n) walk of the list.

**Spoiler:** 
It's not.

But then, the performance of the two versions should be at least comparable, right? I mean:

In the first one, `OrderBy()` allocates a temp array and sorts it in place.
In the second one, I explicitly allocate a list and `Sort()` it in place.

The actual results show that the `OrderBy()` example is 4-5x slower! (5-6 sec vs 1.2-1.3 sec)

**Can anyone come up with an explanation why?**

The `.OrderBy(x => x)` case does execute its `x => x` identity lambda for each element.
The difference between:

```
var result2 = e.Last();
```

and

```
var result2 = e.Select(x=>x).Last();
```

is measurable, but small: 30 - 50 ms more in the second case. So that doesn't explain the huge gap.

Comment: This is why I wish there were versions of `Min()` and `Max()` that returned the object instead of the value. It would avoid the need to sort the entire item set to get the object with the highest or lowest value.

Comment: @itsme86 What do you mean? You can always  do `IEnumerable<MyThing> thingsList = ...; MyThing pubBum = thingsList.Max( thing => thing.BeersBeforeCollapsing ) `

Comment: That returns an `int` assuming `BeersBeforeCollapsing` is an `int`. It could also be a float I guess.

Comment: No, it returns a `MyThing`

Comment: Not on my computer... `MyObj[] foo = { new MyObj { Blee = 7 } }; var bar = foo.Max(o => o.Blee);` `bar` is 7, not the `MyObj` object. If you were able to do that, you wouldn't have to do your `.OrderBy().Last()`, you could just `.Max()`.

Comment: Oh wow, you're right! Sorry, I would have bet on this (and lost money!)

Comment: The reason I used `.Last()` was just a way to force the execution of the Linq chain.  I initially wanted to add a `.ToList()` at the end, but that would have been another allocation.

Comment: Makes sense. Didn't mean to derail your question.

Comment: LINQ to Object doesn't do any clever fusion optimizations. `OrderBy().Last()` is `OrderBy()` followed by `Last()`, and not something that's faster than the individual operations. You're basically asking why the in-place sort operation `List.Sort` (which uses [introsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort)) is faster than `Enumerable.OrderBy` (which uses quicksort, hobbled by the requirement of the comparison going through a key selector lambda). If you wanted to get to the bottom of that, [benchmark.net](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/) could probably tell you.

Comment: Related: [C# Sort and OrderBy comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1832684/4934172). However, the result seems to be different when dealing with objects?

Comment: @itsme86 That's why I have `Aggregate` based `MaxBy` and `MinBy` extensions written.

Comment: I would use `First` instead of `Last`, which avoids the unnecessary traversal of the result since you are just trying to force execution of `OrderBy` in this case.

Comment: It is fast to convert a list to an array. Then you can just use the Max() method. See this example: https://www.dotnetperls.com/max.

Answer (score 4):

It appears that `List` has a [special optimized C++ version of sorting](https://mfranc.com/blog/net-internals-sorting-part2/) it uses when it is comparing types with the `Comparer.Default` or no `IComparer` for the type. `OrderBy` always does a generic sort suitable for any type and `IComparer`.

If you replace the `Select` result with objects of type `MyInt` as follows:

```
public class MyInt : IComparable {
    public int value;
    public MyInt(int newv) => value = newv;

    public int CompareTo(object obj) {
        if (obj is MyInt m2) {
            return value.CompareTo(m2.value);
        }
        else if (obj is int i2) {
            return value.CompareTo(i2);
        }
        else {
            throw new Exception($"can't compare MyInt to {obj.GetType()}");
        }
    }
}

var e = Enumerable.Repeat(1, 10_000_000).Select(_ => new MyInt(r.Next()));
```

Then `OrderBy` will be 2 times faster than the `List.Sort` method.

Note, if you use `Comparer<>.Create` to create a `Comparer` for `MyInt`, `List.Sort` is about on par with `OrderBy`:

```
l.Sort(Comparer<MyInt>.Create((m1,m2) => m1.value.CompareTo(m2.value)));
```