# return Sorted string

Tags: c#, string, sorting

in method `RandomString` i generate a random string and in method `RandomStringSorted` i sort a generate a random string and sort it .

```
public static string RandomString(int length)
       {
           return new string(
               Enumerable.Repeat(
                   "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"+
                   "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"+
                   "0123456789", length)
               .Select(
                   s => s[new Random().Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());
           
       }

       public static string RandomStringSorted(int lenght)
        {
            char[] chars = RandomString(lenght).ToCharArray();
            Array.Sort(chars);
            return new string(chars);
        }
```

Question : Can i return a sorted object . I need Something like :

```
public static string RandomStringSorted(int lenght)
        {
            //I know Array.Sort() is void this is for example what i need.

            return new string(Array.Sort(RandomString(lenght).ToCharArray()));

        }
```

I know `Array.Sort` is `void` this is for example what i need.

Comment: no the sort is a void method and you cant change it but you can write a custom sort method or something like that

Answer (score 2):

If you simply want to sort the generated random string before returning it, you could add an OrderBy to the RandomString method like so:

```
public static string RandomString(int length)
   {
       return new string(
           Enumerable.Repeat(
               "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"+
               "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"+
               "0123456789", length)
           .Select(
               s => s[new Random().Next(s.Length)]).OrderBy(x => x).ToArray());
       
   }
```

Note: Do take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832684/c-sharp-sort-and-orderby-comparison) answer to understand the implications of using Sort vs OrderBy. If you expect to have very large sized strings,OrderBy may not be a good idea due to extra memory footprint.